# Get link to render as html rather than text json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, model-view-controller

I am responding to clicks on `li`'s by using `$.post` to post to an action method in my MVC application.

I want to send a link back in Json.

Can I have this link render as html rather than text ? how ?

I tried this, just to test the html:

```
var link = "<b>Hi</b>";
var encoded = Server.HtmlEncode(link);
```

that came out as `&lt;b&gt;Hi&lt;/b&gt;`

Surely there is just a Json.encode or visual studio method I can use and I don't have to format it myself? Have googled fairly extensively and can't find anything about an Json.encode

```
var link = "<b>Hi</b>";
var encoded = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(link);
```

the page rendered `"\u003cb\u003eHi\u003c/b\u003e"`

If I send just the `link` variable, i.e:

```
var link = "<b>Hi</b>"
```

`<b>Hi</b>` renders

This is the line which sends it back:

`return Json(new {Title = pTitle, Selection = pSelection, Link = pLink}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Starting to get frustrated, wtf!

---

Silly me, I didn't post enough code where the problem was:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function TreeView_onSelect(e) {
    ...
    $.post(url, id, function (data, textStatus) {
    ...
    $("#panel-link").text(data.Link);
    }
```

`$("#panel-link").text(data.Link);`

obv has to be

`$("#panel-link").html(data.Link);`

Comment: I realize that it isn't a link but it doesn't render as bold and exhibits the same problem a link would, but saves me typing as much...

Comment: What if you just don't `HtmlEncode` the string?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx):

```
var link = "<b>Hi</b>";
var encoded = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(link);
```

Comment: Hmmmmm that caused `"\u003cb\u003eHi\u003c/b\u003e"` to render

Answer (score 0):

Try to use javascript's decodeURI() function.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var uri="mytest.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
document.write(encodeURI(uri)+ "<br />");
document.write(decodeURI(uri));

</script>
```

The output of the code above will be:

```
mytest.asp?name=st%C3%A5le&car=saab
mytest.asp?name=ståle&car=saab
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with you and killing me whole day,
I solved this problem by using Json.NET

Sample code is :

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(link);
```

Reference
http://json.codeplex.com/documentation